# PHP square brackets around braces

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having trouble with my array and json_encode. I want it to look like this

```
"invites": [{
  "sent": 0,
  "accepted": 0
}],
```

but it looks like this

```
"shares": {
  "sent": 0,
  "installed": 0
},
```

Currently the code I am using looks like this

```
'shares' => array(
  'sent' => 0,
  'installed' => 0
),
```

Does anyone know how I would go about changing this.
Thanks
Matt

Comment: What is the problem? AFAIK that JSON you get will be converted back to an associative array when you parse it. Have you tried a `var_dump` on your resulting object after parsing it from the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the (associative) array inside another one:

```
'shares' => array(array(
   'sent' => 0,
   'installed' => 0,
))
```

Answer (score 0):

an associative array in php converts to a json object in javascript.

you want:

```
array(
    'shares' => array(
         array('sent' => 0, 'installed' => 0)
     )
)
```

Comment: JSON is not javascript. And this would look like `['shares':{'sent':0,'installed':0}]`. He wants `'shares':[{'sent':0,'installed':0}]` with `'shares'` outside of the array. But you are on the right track.

Comment: @DutGRIFF: was the answer corrected or the output is exactly correct?

Comment: @DutGRIFF The OP is talking about using json_encode() to encode an array... what is 'shares' if not a key for the outermost array?

Comment: @zerkms I don't understand your question. I think Jason meant to put the array around the associative array. There is an array around `'shares'` that OP left off in his post.

Comment: @DutGRIFF: the code from this answer will produce the result exactly as OP requested, that's what my point is.

Comment: I am looking at it differently. If you use something like `array('shares' => array('sent' => 0, 'installed' => 0), 'invites' => array('sent' => 0, 'installed' => 0));` (which I 'think' is what OP has) then you need an array around the associative array not around every item in the top array. I do see what you are saying now. This is what I was thinking OP needed `array('shares' => array(array('sent' => 0, 'installed' => 0)), 'invites' => array(array('sent' => 0, 'installed' => 0)));` which will output `{"shares":[{"sent":0,"installed":0}],"invites":[{"sent":0,"installed":0}]}`